# Why this jquery animate effect doesn't work as I wanted?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, jquery-animate

I want a anchor's hover effect,When I mouse hover on the link,the hovered one could scroll from the top,then mouseout,the unhovered one could scroll from the bottom again.So here is my html code:

```
<div class="viewport">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="scroll hovered" href="#">Hover Now</a>
            <a class="scroll nhover" href="#">Not Hover</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is my jquery code:

```
        $(".container").hover(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                top: '+=22'
            }, 800, 'easeInOutBack');
        }, function () {
            $(this).animate({
                top: '-=22'
            }, 800, 'easeInOutBack');
        });
```

[Then the final result is here](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/x6aVc/1/)

but here is a problem ,when I mover mouse fast on the next link ,the previous one still scrolling,I want prevent this happened,I think about the stop function,so I added ".stop()" before ".animate",like this:

```
        $(".container").hover(function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                top: '+=22'
            }, 800, 'easeInOutBack');
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                top: '-=22'
            }, 800, 'easeInOutBack');
        });
```

However the result doesn't work as I wanted,when I move fast on the link, they disappeared,[look at here](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/CNWV6/)

Why this happened?How can I solve this problem and achieve my goal?Thank you very much!

Comment: The problem is that if you're triggering the hover too soon, the div isn't at top+22, so the next animation moves it upper than it was before. 3nigma's answers solves this (the first is a clearQueue the next is jumpToEnd to force the CSS changes from the parent animation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `.stop(true,true)` it may help

```
      $(".container").hover(function () {
            $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
                top: '+=22'
            }, 800, 'easeInOutBack');
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
                top: '-=22'
            }, 800, 'easeInOutBack');
        });
```

here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNWV6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Best solution i have found so far for this kind of problemms is: [jQuery Hover Intent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

**See working example here:** http://jsfiddle.net/x6aVc/2/